# Show tooltip using jquery when hover on image

Tags: jquery

here i am giving an image that what kind of tooltip i need.

[image]

when some one hover mouse pointer on lifetime warranty image then a tooltip display just under the image and tooltip is positioned in such way that upper image position at center of the below image.

i know how to show tooltip using jquery when hover on image but i am not being able to show tool tip under the image and the hover image is coming center. so i need help. if possible the please help me with sample code. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw earlier a tooltip which seems with one described by you.

Can you use [Coda Bubble Tooltip](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/coda-bubble.html) ?

The home page is http://www.panic.com/coda/

Comment: i dont want to use any plugin. rather i can write code to show a div just under the hover image.i just need to know what will be the calculation to show my tool tip just under the target image and tool tip need to be position like bottom center of hover image. can u plzz tell me the calculation or sample code like that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use css to place the tooltip below the image, the jquery can be used to only show the tooltip or hide it.

Comment: i just need to know what will be the calculation to my tool tip just under the target image and tool tip need to be position like bottom center of hover image. can u plzz tell me the calculation or sample code like that.

Comment: here's a quick code, http://jsfiddle.net/JLaVm/ , change accordingly for the css to suit your page

Comment: that's cool but i want to show red div appear just bottom center of black div. what i need to do but i dont want to manipulate in css rather i need to set the left pos of red div by calculation as a result it will appear just bottom center of black div. please help if possible by changing in ur code. thanks

Comment: what kind of calculation would you mean in this case if not for the css to do the calculation for you?